# React Monaco Editor with python language server - Django Backend

Tags: django, websocket, monaco-editor, channel

all.
I'm working on the project that uses Monaco editor (for python language) on React. But we want to implement IntelliSense to code editor, so it should suggest, autocomplete and so on. For that, I know I should use python language server with web-socket in my back-end, in order to, connect my code editor with python language server. But I cannot get any docs or examples how to use Django web-sockets (i think channels) to connect language server and front end code editor each-other.
I know we should use `monaco-languageclient`, but its docs are not enough and noting for django

Comment: Did you figure this out?